# What is the general solution to differential equation $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} = [1 + \frac{dy}{dx}]^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the general solution to differential equation $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} = [1 + \frac{dy}{dx}]^2$

I have tried squaring it both sides, but it didn't helped, please tell me how to solve the problems with degree more than 1.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right equation? $\cosh$ doesn't solve it.

Comment: I have cross checked the question, and based on the answers given below  I got  $ y =  -ln(x+c_1) - x + c_2 $ but this is not matching with the given answer, is the answer given to the question is wrong?

Comment: Eliminating the constants by differentiation gives $$y'=\sinh(x+c_1)\implies y''=\cosh(x+c_1)=\sqrt{1+y'^2}.$$ Did you mix up differential equations and answers?

Comment: To get the answer you want, you'd need equation $$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 1 +\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$$

Comment: Yes the question has mistake in it. To match the given answer it must be in the form $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 1 +\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ @AdamLatosiński

Comment: Yes the question has mistake in it, it should be $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 1 +\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ @LutzL

Comment: Then you get $y'=\tan(x+c_1)$, $y=\ln|\cos(x+c_1)|+c_2$, which is still different

Comment: @LutzL Right. Let me correct myself: You'd need $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} $

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote. @AdamLatosiński

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take dy/dx=t
Then equation changes to:
$dt/dx=(1+t)^2$.can you proceed now?

Comment: Yes, I got  $ y =  -ln(x+c_1) - x + c_2$ but this is not matching with the given answer, is the answer given to the question is wrong?

Comment: Sorry sir, I don't know it

Comment: $$\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$ $$\text{arcosh}(x)=\cosh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$$ This still doesn't match it with the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dv}{dx}=(1+v)^2$$ where $v=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

Integrate both sides

$-\dfrac1{1+v}=x+c$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant

$\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=v=-\dfrac1{x+c}-1$

Integrate both sides